# using .closest with .click

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use .closest to grab the closest `<li>` value based on clicking one of the `<li>` elements.  I'm not having much luck.  First off, I'm not having much luck trying to figure out how to add the `.click` part to the `.closest`.

Thanks in advance.

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() { 



 var test = $('#test').closest('li').text();

 alert(test);

 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<tbody>


<ul id="test">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Accept some answers in your previous questions.

Comment: Side note: I see that you use a `tbody` element in the `body` element, that is not correct. A `tbody` element is only used as a child to a `table` element.

Comment: `closest()` looks for the closest parent, not children of the element. Use `children()` for immediate children or `find()` for any children of the element.

Answer (score 1):

To hook up the onclick event you use the `click` method and provide a function as event handler:

```
$('li').click(function() { ... });
```

In the event handler you can use `this` to access the element that was clicked on:

```
var test = $(this).text();
```

As you are getting the text inside the element, you don't want to use the `closest` method as that is used to find a different element (specifically a decendant element).

So:

```
$(function() { 

  $('li').click(function() {
    var test = $(this).text();
    alert(test);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the post!  I'm trying to apply it this way without any success.  Where am I messing up?   $(function() {


 
 $('.vote').click(function() { 
 
 var vote = $(this).text();
 alert(vote);
 
 
 });
 
 });
});

<span class="vote">Vote</span>

Comment: @user550495: You have one too many `});` in that code. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8EvB/

Comment: That works great!   However, what i'm trying to do is get a unique value identified with the vote text.  Ie <span class="vote" id="123456"> i want to grab that Id so i know what to pass to the db.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user550495: You can get the id of the clicked element using `$(this).attr('id')`.